# Flask-SQLalchemy: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The code:

```
def get_average(questions):
        i = []
        for question in questions.items:
            if question.correct:
                i.append(question)
        return len(i) * 10
```

Gives the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'` when run. The `questions` parameter is passed a flask-sqlalchemy pagination object, [viewable here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L304).

This should be a list, and when running the code:

```
for x in questions.items:
        print(x.correct)
```

it works fine and as expected. What has changed to cause this error. Both bits of code use the same `questions` object.

The entire view function is as follows:

```
students = current_user.students

student_averages = {}

for student in students:
    student_averages[student.username] = (student, [])
    student_avg_list = student_averages[student.username][1]

    questions = student.questions.paginate(page=1, per_page=10)

    for x in questions.items:  # Works
        print(x.question_text)

    def get_average(questions):
        i = []
        for question in questions.items:  # Gives error
            if question.correct:
                i.append(question)
        return len(i) * 10
```

Comment: I searched my project and couldn't find one, I also tried changing the name of the parameter to `x`, and still got the same error.

Comment: You need to show the full code. What is calling this function, and where is the value for the questions parameter defined?

Comment: I would put a `print(type(questions))` line immediately inside the `get_average` function definition to ensure you are actually passing a pagination object to it. Also as Daniel said we need to see the code up to where you are invoking `get_average` and it is throwing an error. Make sure there isn't something you are missing and just need a fresh set of eyes.